# How do I edit a Texture2D at run-time to visually indicate connected tiles?

Tags: c#, directx, sprites, monogame

I'm making a 2D sandbox game in C# and MonoGame, and I have a couple of tile sprites. These tile are loaded in-game as `Texture2D`s. I want to have blocks visually connect to adjacent blocks.

An example:

This is how a tile would look if it was connected to another tile to its *right side*:

[image: connected on right]

Here's if *all of its sides* were connected:

[image: connected on all sides]

If *none of its sides* were connected at all:

[image: unconnected, floating alone]

I think you see the idea. Starbound and Terraria do a similar thing.

I don't want to have like 10 different textures for each block for every combination of every side, as that needlessly takes up space.

What can I do in the code to edit my existing sprites to look like this? Am I just better off going with 10 different textures? Or maybe there's something better I've missed?

Comment: Rocking first question! ★ I'd be interested in an answer that actually creates appropriate tile textures *at runtime*. Then you could even procedurally generate the tile sprites themselves.

Comment: Thanks, for both that comment and editing (nearly my whole post) to make it more understandable. I was a little tired when writing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the texture, if you're changing the texture based on orthogonal connections, you'll only need 5 (if the texture can be rotated) or as many as 15.

The simplest solution is to create these textures manually. You'll have a much easier time getting the visuals right.

As for deciding which to use, see this question and answer: [Choose tile based on adjacent tiles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29524/choose-tile-based-on-adjacent-tiles)

Comment: Ok, thanks. It will be a small pain to load these textures and manage them, but I will try my best to make this work out.
Thanks again.

Comment: Just wrap the functionality of loading, and selecting the correct version in a class, and you'll be alright :).